# How to automate a webbrowser that supports javascript?

Tags: scripting, web

I have to automate the "imitation" of a "human" by using a webbrowser that supports javascript.

I need it because there is a javascript link on the website that can be only used if the webbrowser supports javascript, so curl/wget cannot do it.

**Question:** How can I do this on a Linux terminal? Or is it impossible?

Comment: Have you tried [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)? or [watir](http://watir.com/)?

Comment: [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox), [WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS)...

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using two ways:

1. GUI way ==> Use Selenium
2. Terminal way ==> Use `ghost.py` or `phantomjs`

### Terminal Way

You can go ahead and use `ghost.py` or `phantomjs`. Read their documentations on how to use them here : [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) and [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html)

#### An example using Ghost.py

First install `ghost.py`. To install this, you will need `pip`. Hence, do this on a ubuntu based system:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install Ghost.py
```

Now, you can use `Ghost.py` in your script to automate any javascript based actions. Here is a sample script derived from  the official documentation:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
#script.py

from ghost import Ghost 
ghost = Ghost()

page, resources = ghost.open('http://my.web.page')

#Run javascript action
result, resources = ghost.evaluate( "document.getElementById('my-input').getAttribute('value');")
```